# pip install django --upgrade installs older version

Tags: django, upgrade, pip

I had installed a development version of django on my dev box (django 1.3 alpha1). I want to upgrade to latest version..  when I :

`pip install django --upgrade`

I get version 1.2.3 for some reason.  How do I use pip to upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: Found the answer, if you delete the django folder in your build directory (using a virtualenv btw) and then try the upgrade again it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer, if you delete the django folder in your build directory (using a virtualenv btw) and then try the upgrade again it will work.